# How to write a code which checks if we have again this same value in index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
connect = {'2': ['1', '3'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '4': ['3']}
```

How to write a code which checks if we have again this same value in index?

example: if we append `'2':['1']` we get:

```
'2': ['1', '3'] not '2': ['1','1', '3']
```

Comment: How do you plan to append `'2':['1']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending if you dont need to preserve order or not you could convert your list values as sets since sets dont allow duplicates.

```py
connect = {'2': ['1', '3'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '4': ['3']}
set_connect = {k: set(v) for k, v in connect.items()}
print(set_connect)
set_connect['2'].add('1')
print(set_connect)
set_connect['2'].add('5')
print(set_connect)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'2': {'1', '3'}, '1': {'2'}, '3': {'4', '2'}, '4': {'3'}}
{'2': {'1', '3'}, '1': {'2'}, '3': {'4', '2'}, '4': {'3'}}
{'2': {'5', '1', '3'}, '1': {'2'}, '3': {'4', '2'}, '4': {'3'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_append( c, k, v ):
    if v not in c[k]:
        c[k].append(v)

connect = {'2': ['1', '3'], '1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '4': ['3']}
print connect
my_append(connect, '2', '1')
print connect
my_append(connect, '2', '4')
print connect
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '2': ['1', '3'], '4': ['3']}
{'1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '2': ['1', '3'], '4': ['3']}
{'1': ['2'], '3': ['2', '4'], '2': ['1', '3', '4'], '4': ['3']}
```